# Fundamental group of Klein Bottle

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, klein-bottle

It is well know that the fundamental group of the Klein Bottle $G$ is defined by

$$G=BS(1,-1)=\langle a,b: bab^{-1}=a^{-1}\rangle.$$

I know, for example  that $BS(1,2)$ can be defined as the group

$$BS(1,2)=\langle A,B\rangle $$

where

$$A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right), B=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right).$$

These matrices satisfy the equation $BAB^{-1}=A^{2}$ and are free : there is not an integer $k$ such that $A^{k}=I$ or $B^{k}=I$. This implies that we obtain an "explicit description" of $BS(1,2)$ as the group generated by $A$ and $B$.

I know that the matrices

$$a=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right), b=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

satisfy the relation $bab^{-1}=a^{-1}$ but $b^{2}=I$. This implies that $BS(1,-1)$ is not generated by $a$ and $b$.

> My question is: is there an "explicit description" for $G=BS(1,-1)$ with matrices or maybe another couple of objects?

Comment: Are [Deck transformations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312936/fundamental-group-of-the-klein-bottle-using-action-of-a-group) of $\mathbb{R}^2$ good enough?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identifying $\langle a,b\mid a^2b^2\rangle$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2782481/identifying-langle-a-b-mid-a2b2-rangle)

Comment: @PaulPlummer by deck transformation of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ do you mean that $BS(1-1)$ can be defined as the group generated by the homeomorphism $f(x,y)=(x,y+1), g(x,y)=(x+1,1-y)$ ?

Comment: Yah, those are the "standard" maps. Seems pretty explicit to me (isometries of $\mathbb{R}^2$).

Comment: My motivation is give a linear action of $G$ over $M$ such that $H^{0}(G,M)=0$ but $H^{1}(G,M)\neq 0$ where $M=\mathbb{R}$ or $M=\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Comment: @Shaun the group in your suggested duplicate is a different group from this one.

Comment: They're isomorphic, @StevenStadnicki; see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2782901/104041).

Comment: While the groups are isomorphic, nonetheless I don't think the question is a duplicate. This one asks for a more "explicit description" with the suggestion of matrices, which is a good question. @Shaun

Comment: That's a fair comment, @LeeMosher; I'll withdraw my vote to close.

Comment: @LeeMosher By the way how can we define a linear action of $G$ over $\mathbb{R}^{2}$?

Comment: That's an interesting question, but it would be better to ask it in a new post rather than as a comment to this post.

Comment: I'd missed the isomorphism; mea culpa!!

Comment: Here is a meta-answer: $\operatorname{BS}(1,-1)$ contains $\mathbb{Z}^2$ as an index-$2$ subgroup. As $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is linear over $\mathbb{Z}$, we immediately have that $\operatorname{BS}(1,-1)$ is linear over $\mathbb{Z}$, as virtually-linear implies linear. So yes, there *is* an explicit description in terms of integer matrices, and it can be computed.

Comment: @user1729 Thank you. I'm doing the computations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting from the representation described by @PaulPlummer as a group of isometries of $\mathbb R^2$, you can obtain a representation as a group of linear transformations of $\mathbb R^3$.

To do this, one uses a standard embedding of the isometry group of $\mathbb R^2$ as a subgroup of $GL(3,\mathbb R)$. Each isometry of $\mathbb R^2$ can be written uniquely as $P \mapsto MP + Q$ for some $M \in O(2,\mathbb R)$ and some $Q \in \mathbb R^2$ (vectors are written in column format). The representing element of $GL(3,\mathbb R)$ is the matrix written in block form as $\pmatrix{M & Q \\ 0 & 1}$. If you then represent a column 2-vector $P$ as a column 3-vector $\pmatrix{P \\ 1}$ then matrix multiplication gives you
$$\pmatrix{M & Q \\ 0 & 1}\pmatrix{P \\ 1} =  \pmatrix{MP+Q \\ 1}
$$

For the Klein bottle group, the two generators are:

1. A translation $1$ unit to the right:
   $$P \mapsto M_1 P + Q_1, \qquad M_1 = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}, \qquad Q_1 = \pmatrix{1 \\ 0}
   $$
2. A glide reflector, gliding up the $y$-axis by $1$ unit:
   $$P \mapsto M_2 P + Q_2, \qquad M_2 = \pmatrix{-1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}, \qquad Q_2 = \pmatrix{0 \\ 1}
   $$

Answer (score 2):

Finally , $G$ can be described as the group of $2\times 2$ matrices generated by two matrix $A,B$ such that $BAB^{-1}=A^{-1}$ and $A^{k}\neq I$, $B^{k}\neq I$ for all $k$. Let $A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
 c &  d\\
\end{array}
\right)$ and $B=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \lambda & 0 \\
 0 & \mu \\
\end{array}
\right)$ (to simplify computations). Working whith the equation $BAB^{-1}=A^{-1}$ and assuming that $ad-bc=1$ and $b,c\neq 0$ we have that

$A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
 c &  a\\
\end{array}
\right)$ and $B=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \lambda & 0 \\
 0 & -\lambda \\
\end{array}
\right)$

This family of matrices satisfy the relation $BAB^{-1}=A^{-1}$.

If $A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 3 \\
 1 &  2\\
\end{array}
\right)$ and $B=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 0 \\
 0 & -2 \\
\end{array}
\right)$, then $BAB^{-1}=A^{-1}$  and $A^{k}\neq I$, $B^{k}\neq I$, for all $k$

Hence $G\equiv \langle A,B\rangle$.

Comment: There could be other relations in your matrix group so you haven't shown it is $G$ yet

Comment: @PaulPlummer In that case a new question comes to me: is there two $2\times 2$ matrices $A,B$ such that $G\equiv <A,B>$ ?

Comment: I think it is likely that this will do it but you just haven't fully shown it(shouldn't be too bad it)

Comment: Building on JCAA's deleted answer: $G=\langle A, B\rangle$ is in fact $\operatorname{BS}(1, -1)$. The idea is to prove that $G=\mathbb{Z\rtimes Z}$ with the appropriate action, and the only thing needed to prove this is to show that $\langle A\rangle\cap\langle B\rangle=1$. To see this, note that $A$ contains only *positive* integers, and so any positive power of $A$ also contains only positive integers (as components in such a power are obtained by *adding* components in $A$). In particular, $A^k$ is non-diagonal for all $k>0$.  cont.

Comment: In contrast, every power of $B$ (positive power or negative power) is diagonal. Hence, $\langle A\rangle\cap\langle B\rangle$ is trivial, as required.

Comment: I am rather surprised that you found this example in $2\times2$ matrices, so good job! In my original comment to the question, I had in mind starting with a copy of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ in $\operatorname{GL}(3, \mathbb{Z})$, and then the rank would increase to construct a copy of $\operatorname{BS}(1, -1)$. To find an example over integer matrices the rank would have to be at least $3$, as $\operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$ is virtually free (your group $G$ does not lie in $\operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$, as $B^{-1}$ is not integer-valued).

Comment: @user1729 So... are you agree whit my answer? Does A and B generate the Group G?

Comment: @JoseCamarillo Lets be precise: The matrices $A$ and $B$ generate a group isomorphic to the fundamental group of the Klein bottle. (But they *do not* generate the fundamental group of the Klein bottle. In my above comments, I was writing $G$ as shorthand for $\langle A, B\rangle$, so my $G$ is different from your $G$.)